# Android popBackStackImmediate animate the backstack fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am stuck at getting back fragment's animated. I am adding fragments like this

```
A3Fragment a3Fragment = new A3Fragment();

FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left,
                        R.anim.slide_out_right, R.anim.slide_in_right);

transaction.addToBackStack(null); 

transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_mainLayout, a3Fragment).commit();
```

But when i do a popBackStackImmediate the fragment that is getting popped is animated out. But i cannot get the fragment that is going to be shown next (The fragment that was in the stack) to animate. Is there a way to animate this back fragment ?

Comment: any solution you got ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

setCustomAnimations(int enter, int exit, int popEnter, int popExit)

```
transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left, R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right);
```